# phayser can not stop sound loop in firefox

Tags: firefox, phaser-framework

```
music = game.sound.play('loop4');
music.loopFull();
music.stop();
```

thiese code work well in chrome except firefox

how can I play loop sound in fireFox and then stop it

Comment: Impossible to answer with only "code doesn't work well" in FireFox. What exactly goes wrong? It doesn't loop? It doesn't play at all? Any error messages? etc.

Comment: the code has no error  on console and  line-3 can  not stop the looping audio

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//Add sound
var music = game.add.audio('loop4');
//Start loop
music.loopFull();
//Stop loop
music.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, it could be a bug. But it's also weird that you start and then immediately on the next line stop the music. Maybe that is not the intended use. If you try something like this, does it then start playing and stop after 2 seconds?

```
music = game.sound.play('loop4');
music.loopFull();

// wait 2 seconds then stop
game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 2, doStopMusic, this);

// separate function to stop music
function doStopMusic() {
    // note: music must be global variable
    music.stop();
}
```